# Double square intersection symbol ⩎

Tags: symbols

I want this ⩎ symbol I tried using \Sqcap but latex gave me the error : "undefined control sequence"
Am i missing something?

This is my code:

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\allowdisplaybreaks[3]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
%\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xy}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amscd}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsthm}
 
 \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\input xy 
\xyoption{all}

%\xyoption{all}
\input{dinmacros.tex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
%\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,calc,shapes.multipart}
\tikzstyle{obj} =[circle, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, draw=black]
\overfullrule=0.2mm
\def\justl#1#2{\\
        &#1& \rule{2em}{0pt} \{
        \mbox{\rule[-.7em]{0pt}{1.8em} \footnotesize{#2}} \} \\ && }


\def\cat#1{{\sf #1}}
\def\setcat{\cat{Set}}
\def\Mmax{\cat{MAX}}
\def\Mmin{\cat{MIN}}
\def\bmax{\cat{max}}
\def\bmin{\cat{min}}
\newcommand{\fdec}[3]{#1: #2 \longrightarrow #3}
\newcommand{\rfdec}[3]{#1: #2 \rightarrow #3}
\def\setdef#1#2{\{#1\; |\;#2\}}             % { f(x) | p(x) }
\def\enset#1{\mathopen{ \{ }#1\mathclose{ \} }} % {a,b,...z}



\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
%\newtheorem{proof}{proof.}
\newenvironment{proof}{\noindent \textbf{Proof.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition} Given a \emph{iMTL-algebra \pmb{A}} enriched with a metric $d$, a \emph{\pmb{A}- twisted algebra} $\pmb{A^2}=\langle A \times A, \Sqcap \rangle$ is defined as:
\\for any $(a,b),\, (c,d) \in A \times A$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please give a complete example. This will depend on what package, font and engine you are using.

Comment: @mickep thank you, i edited my question

Comment: `\Sqcap` comes from the `fdsymbol` package. It is a synonym for `\doublesqcap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mathabx` package defines `\sqdoublecap` (and `\sqdoublecup` for ⩏):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
Double square intersection: $\sqdoublecap$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `unicode-math` and `IEEEtran`, you should use Times as the text font and you can exploit the STIX Two fonts.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,calc,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{tikz-network}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\tikzstyle{obj} =[circle, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, draw=black]

%\input{dinmacros.tex}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newcommand\justl[2]{\\
        &#1& \rule{2em}{0pt} \{
        \mbox{\rule[-.7em]{0pt}{1.8em} \footnotesize #2} \} \\ && }


\newcommand\cat[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
\newcommand\setcat{\cat{Set}}
\newcommand\Mmax{\cat{MAX}}
\newcommand\Mmin{\cat{MIN}}
\newcommand\bmax{\cat{max}}
\newcommand\bmin{\cat{min}}
\newcommand{\fdec}[3]{#1: #2 \longrightarrow #3}
\newcommand{\rfdec}[3]{#1: #2 \rightarrow #3}
\newcommand\setdef[2]{\{#1\; |\;#2\}}             % { f(x) | p(x) }
\newcommand\enset[1]{\mathopen{ \{ }#1\mathclose{ \} }} % {a,b,...z}



\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
%\newtheorem{proof}{proof.}
%\newenvironment{proof}{\noindent \textbf{Proof.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition} 
Given a \emph{iMTL-algebra} $\symbfit{A}$ enriched with a metric $d$, an 
\emph{$\symbfit{A}$-twisted algebra} 
$\symbfit{A}^2=\langle A \times A, \Sqcap \rangle$ is defined as:
for any $(a,b),\, (c,d) \in A \times A$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Please, check the modified preamble, where I got rid of duplication and suggested other *necessary* changes.

[image]

Comment: It is very interesting that if I write in the source file `$⟨A × A, ⩎⟩$`, the result is ⟨ × , ⩏⟩ and if I write `$⟨A × A, ⩏⟩$` then the result is  ⟨ × , ⩎⟩.

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in Unicode table, where the visual of "Double Square Intersection" looks like "Double Square Union" and vice versa.

Comment: @wipet Not on my machine. And in `unicode-math-table`, `\Sqcap` is associated to U+2A4E, and `\Sqcup` to U+2A4F, which is correct.

Comment: OK, it is a bug in the font in my OS which is used for such symbols. For example I see (in my web browser) the title of this thread as: "Double square intersection symbol" followed by something which looks like double square union.