# How to input double square intersection

Tags: math-operators, unicode-math, mathabx

I would like a [double square intersection symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659093/double-square-intersection-symbol-%E2%A9%8E) in my Overleaf document without having to change the main font (I am using the AMS packages and the standard Latin Modern).

While an answer given in the hyperlink suggests `\usepackage{mathabx}` (producing the desired outcome), it makes me change my entire font class. How can I extract the symbol from this package and make sure it is the same size as the other symbols (such as `\cap, \cup`, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Unicode math and xits math font, then you have no problem. For example in OpTeX: `\fontfam[xits] $X⩎Y$ \bye`

Comment: You can start here: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the procedure for `mathabx`.

1. Look in the manual of `mathabx` for the symbol name: it is `\sqdoublecap`
2. Look in `mathabx.dcl` for the command to find

   `\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqdoublecap}   {2}{mathb}{"5E}`
3. Look in `mathabx.sty` for the symbol font `mathb` to find

   ```
   \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
   \DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
         <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
         <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
         }{}
   \DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
   \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
   ```

We have all the ingredients.

Add to your document preamble

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqdoublecap}{2}{mathb}{"5E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqdoublecup}{2}{mathb}{"5F}
```

Why the changes?

- `\hyphenchar\font` makes no sense for symbol fonts;
- the fonts are available in Type1 format, so we can define them at any size, not just at the traditional fixed sizes.

I also added `\sqdoublecup` for symmetry.

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% import from mathabx
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqdoublecap}{2}{mathb}{"5E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqdoublecup}{2}{mathb}{"5F}
% end import

\begin{document}

$A\sqcap B\sqdoublecap C$

$A\sqcup B\sqdoublecup C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Oh, well, it's not the same size as `\sqcap`, is it?

OK, let's measure the symbols: add

```
\sbox0{$\sqcap$}\the\ht0

\sbox0{$\sqdoublecap$}\the\ht0
```

and see that you get 5.55557pt for the former and 6.83167pt for the latter. If we divide we get, approximately, 0.8132. So we can apply this magnification, changing

```
<-5.5> mathb5
```

into

```
<-5.5> s*[0.8132] mathb5
```

and similarly for the other lines. We get now

[image]

Darn! It's too small! A problem of bounding boxes, apparently. Now we have to gauge by eye. Let's try with `0.87`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}% just for the final comparison

% import from mathabx
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> s*[0.87] mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> s*[0.87] mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> s*[0.87] mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> s*[0.87] mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> s*[0.87] mathb9
  <9.5-11> s*[0.87] mathb10
  <11-> s*[0.87] mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqdoublecap}{2}{mathb}{"5E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqdoublecup}{2}{mathb}{"5F}
% end import

\begin{document}

$A\sqcap B\sqdoublecap C$

$A\sqcup B\sqdoublecup C$

{\ooalign{\color{red}$\sqcap$\cr$\sqdoublecap$\cr}}

\end{document}
```

The last line superimposes the two symbols, one red colored.

[image]

Not *exactly* the same height and width, but the differences are negligible.

***Important***

If you're short of symbol fonts (there are only 16 available families with `pdftex` and a few are already taken), you can remove the `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\DeclareMathSymbol` lines, replacing them with

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqdoublecap}{\mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}\symbol{"5E}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqdoublecup}{\mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}\symbol{"5F}}}}
```

that doesn't waste a symbol font for just a couple of symbols.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thank you very much.